# How can I assign a max limit to margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div floating at the right side of the page. Using a plugin, it goes up and down when the window is scrolled vertically.

```
      upwards
        ^
        |
        |

-------------------
|                  |
|   The scrollable |
|      DIV         |
|                  |   
--------------------
        |
        |

     downwards
```

The scrollable DIV is like a Cart Summary Box. The problem is that when the scroll is made the div keeps scrolling down until you keep scrolling. I want to set a dynamic maximum margin-top for it. The scrolling is happening because of the change in its margin-top. Is there anyway, I can restrict that to happen?
The page contains other elements on the left which can shrink or expand. I want the max scrollable  height to be adjusted accordingly to the height of parent div.

Thanks for a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's almost impossible to tell you how to fix that without you posting some code.

I would recommend you use [jQuery Stick'em](http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em) to achieve that

Comment: @Ahmed - Thanks ! Stick'em is good. But the one I felt that best worked for me, is a plugin called [jScroll](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/jScroll "Click to visit jScroll plugin website").